# How to write a pop-up window in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a pop-up window like this one:
http://gyazo.com/48a138b2e40fda7e5e72acd1b653a518
in JavaScript.

When the administrator clicks on `Delete` link one parameter should be passed to JavaScript on-click function.

How can I bind different actions to OK and Cancel buttons ? 
My actions are like this one below:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/Invalidate.do?val=INVALIDATE"/>">Logout</a>
```

Could anyone help me writing this piece of code (complete on-click function)? 
It would be great if you also show me how to attach this on-click to my link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: jstl tag from jsp core library.
I need to put on-click JavaScript on this link or similar one. This one is just a sort of reference

Comment: ok, just wondering - it wasn't any templating language I knew of. But your server-side stuff shouldn't impact the answer to this question.

Comment: But that's the problem. 
I must create my own CustomTag. And this tag iterates over ArrayList<> and shows Object properties from it. In addition, it adds two links for each item: Edit and Delete. If admin clicks on Delete link - he should get this pop-up window first. So I have to hardcode all this stuff in a manner like that: out.println("<td>" + user.getLogin() + "</td>"); And I also have to include JavaScript function in it.

Comment: `confirm` returns true for OK and false for Cancel.

Comment: I think you're really lacking in some background on how javascript programming works. I really recommend you go and read a few articles on getting started with javascript and maybe that will help answer some of your questions. It really has nothing to do with the java code you're writing up there - java and javascript are two completely different languages with similar names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm) for simple stuff.

It works if you don't mind all your javascript blocking and no control over styling.

`confirm` and `alert` are built into all browsers but they're very limited and usually not a terribly good idea for anything beyond one-offs.

For far more control you would have to bring in something like [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) or [bootbox from bootstrap](http://bootboxjs.com/) which is just html and therefore infinitely more flexible. But also more of a hassle to set up unless you're already using the library in question. Also all of these will not block javascript execution which, again, is way more powerful and better "practice" but also harder for people - especially beginners - to get their heads around.

so you can do something like (assuming jQuery):

```
$('button[name=delete]').click(function() {
  if(window.confirm("You really sure?"))
     doDelete();
});
```

or using jQuery ui:

```
$('button[name=delete]').click(function() {
    $('<div>').text("You really sure?")  //Create a simple text element to be dialog'ed
        .dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function(){
                    doDelete()
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
                ,"No": function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
        });
});
```

for completeness sake, here's a slick way of removing that redundant code:

```
$('button[name=delete]').click(function() {
    $('<div>').text("You really sure?")  //Create a simple text element to be dialog'ed
        .dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Yes": closeAnd(doDelete)
                ,"No": closeAnd()
        });
    function closeAnd(fn) {   //this function is automatically hoisted
        return function() {   //return a handler
             $(this).dialog('close');  //value of 'this' is determined by who invokes it               
             fn && fn();   //invoke fn if it was passed
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for info. I have some further questions:
1) how can I bind this script to my <href> html element ?
2) how should I import library in order to make it work ?
I can't really understand your doDelete() function.

Comment: `doDelete` doesn't exist because I don't know what doing a delete means for you. You might be only doing something on the client or you might do an ajax request or multiple ones - I have no way of knowing without knowing your app so it's just a function that I assume exists somewhere in scope.

`<href>` is not an html element, it is an attribute of an `<a>` element. Again, assumign jQuery - instead of `$('button[name=delete]')` you would use the appropriate selector for your `<a>` element. You probably want to add a class to it and do something like `$('a.deleteItem')`

Comment: As for how to import a library, that is way more than I can explain simply in a comment and goes back to understanding how javascript and html works. You can try getting started [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery). For jQuery Ui you would need both a script and css reference

Comment: There is one link which I'd like to bind this javascript function:
<a href="/DeleteServlet.do?userId=1">Delete</a> 
How can I bind on-click to this link ?

Comment: with jQuery that is what the `.click()` function does - it binds a callback to run when that element is clicked on. If you need to get the url you can do so within the click function handler (but not any functions within that) with `var url = $(this).attr('href');`